# Adding NotebookDirectory to $Path when notebook opens

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

I'm trying to get relative notebook paths work without evaluating `$Path = Append[$Path, NotebookDirectory[]];` each time I open a notebook.

A bonus would be to keep it working this way only in regular notebooks, not in Packages.

Comment: I believe it's easier just to include this line in initialization cell. Beacuse it seems not an obvious task to modify $path this way. Usually for such things one just modifies kernel start file init.m, but there you can't use NotebookDirectory[].. that's much different. Maybe it is possible to modify frontend/init.m with open-event by FrontEndExecute..

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. It just seems such an obvious thing to have when you work with data that I thought someone has already done it, without making an initialization cell in each such notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much more complicated solution, but it doesn't contain anything "illegal" like adding non-string to `$Path`. It supports multiple notebooks in session chosen with customizable criteria.

Add following to your "global" `init.m`, or e.g. save it in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/PathAutoUpdate/init.m` file:

```
Begin["PathAutoUpdate`"]

(* Variable containing list of notebook directories
   that where automatically added to $Path. *)
$nbDirsOnPath = {}

(* Variable containing function selecting notebook objects,
   which directories are intended to be on $Path. *)
$nbIntendedForPathQ = AbsoluteCurrentValue[#, StyleDefinitions] === "Default.nb"&

updatePath[] := (
    (* Remove from $Path automatically added notebook directories. *)
    $Path = DeleteCases[$Path, Alternatives @@ $nbDirsOnPath];

    (* List of notebook directories, of all currently open and saved notebooks,
       that are not already on $Path. *)
    $nbDirsOnPath =
        Complement[
            Cases[
                Quiet[
                    NotebookDirectory /@ Select[Notebooks[], $nbIntendedForPathQ],
                    {NotebookDirectory::nosv}
                ]
                ,
                _String
            ]
            ,
            $Path
        ];

    $Path = Join[$Path, $nbDirsOnPath];
)

(* If previous CellProlog was set by setCellProlog use one before previous. *)
updatePathRestoreCellProlog[CellProlog :> updatePathRestoreCellProlog[oldCellProlog_]] :=
    updatePathRestoreCellProlog[oldCellProlog]
updatePathRestoreCellProlog[oldCellProlog_] := (
    updatePath[];
    oldCellProlog[[2]];
    SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, oldCellProlog]
)

(* Function setting CellProlog to function that updates $Path only on first evaluation. *)
setCellProlog[] :=
    With[{oldCellProlog = First[Options[$FrontEndSession, CellProlog]]},
        SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
            CellProlog :> updatePathRestoreCellProlog[oldCellProlog]
        ]
    ]

switchOn[global_:True] :=
    SetOptions[If[TrueQ[global], $FrontEnd, $FrontEndSession],
        FrontEndEventActions -> {
            {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> setCellProlog[],
            {"MenuCommand", "Open"} :> setCellProlog[],
            "WindowClose" :> setCellProlog[],
            PassEventsDown -> True
        },
        CellProlog :> updatePathRestoreCellProlog[CellProlog -> None]
    ]

switchOff[global_:True] :=
    SetOptions[If[TrueQ[global], $FrontEnd, $FrontEndSession],
        FrontEndEventActions -> None,
        CellProlog -> None
    ]

End[]
```

## Basic usage

You can switch on automatic updating of `$Path` by evaluating

```
PathAutoUpdate`switchOn[]
```

From now on directories containing saved versions of all open notebooks will be on `$Path`. When any notebook is saved, opened or closed `$Path` will automatically update.

Code updating `$Path` is saved in global FrontEnd options, so it will be still active after restarting Mathematica.

If you want to turn on `$Path` updating only for current session evaluate

```
PathAutoUpdate`switchOn[False]
```

To turn off `$Path` updating evaluate

```
PathAutoUpdate`switchOff[]
```

or

```
PathAutoUpdate`switchOff[False]
```

## Customization

Notebooks, which directories are added to `$Path`, are selected using function stored in `$nbIntendedForPathQ` variable.

By default only notebooks with `"Default.nb"` style are selected. This excludes e.g. packages and documentation notebooks. But if you use custom styles on your notebooks, you should adapt `$nbIntendedForPathQ` function. You can choose arbitrary selection criterion, not necessarily based on notebook style.

## Uninstallation

To completely remove all changes introduced by `` PathAutoUpdate` ``, remove its code from where you saved it and restore default values of global FrontEnd options: `FrontEndEventActions` and `CellProlog`.

<sub>Code tested in Mathematica versions 8.0, 9.0 and 10.0.</sub>

Comment: I can't thank you enough for sharing this - it works exactly as intended :) Too bad something so simple required so much work in Mathematica..

Comment: @Ranza I'm glad someone found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to include a function in your `$Path` that always evaluates to a valid file-name. If you are in a saved notebook, it evaluates to its folder, if not that it maybe evaluates to your user documents directory. A simple solution for this could be

```
nbPath[] := Quiet[With[{p = NotebookDirectory[]},
   If[p =!= $Failed, p, $UserDocumentsDirectory]
]]

Block[{nbPath},
 AppendTo[$Path, nbPath[]]
]
```

Now your last entry `$Path` changes when evaluated in different notebooks. Be aware, that I have a bad feeling about changing such a fundamental *Mathematica* variable this way. Additionally, this seems to lead to an error message when you call `Quit`.

Comment: Oh, that looks interesting thank you! Nevertheless I'd like to keep the question open - perhaps we can find something that will not break existing things...

Comment: @Ranza And you should keep it open, because this hack really infers with the system as far as I have seen.